# Backpacking Jamaica in February

Tags: covid-19, backpacking, jamaica

I would like to ask for advice: I have a free week in February, and I was considering going to Jamaica. I have one friend who would join, so we would be two young guys leaving wives home and looking for some fun - by that I mean bars, sights, nature and so on. Renting a car & staying in hostels far from any resort. We did travel in SE Asia like that a few times before Covid. My question: Does this make sense regarding the Covid situation? Is there any nightlife or has it died? Are there similiary minded travelers present on the island?